# How to fix "java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key algorithm: EC. Only RSA supported" while using Keystore in api 18

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

I need to store sensitive data in local storage with an API 18 , i choose to use the Keystore. I try several solution but none worked.

I try to make my RSAPrivateKey in PrivateKey without cast but it don't work.
I also try to use other crypting algorithm but i never success to make them work in API 18

```java
public String decryptString(String alias, String encryptedText) {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
String decryptedText = "";
        try {
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
            RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();

            Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

            CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT)), output);
            ArrayList<Byte> values = new ArrayList<>();
            int nextByte;
            while ((nextByte = cipherInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                values.add((byte)nextByte);
            }

            byte[] bytes = new byte[values.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                bytes[i] = values.get(i).byteValue();
            }

            decryptedText = new String(bytes, 0, bytes.length, "UTF-8");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }
```

```java
public String encryptString(String alias, String initialText) {
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        String encryptedText = "";
        try {
            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry)keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
            PublicKey publicKey = privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
            // Encrypt the text
            if(initialText.isEmpty()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "initialText is Empty");
                return "";
            }

            Cipher input = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            input.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);//Need RSA private or public key

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(
                    outputStream, input);
            cipherOutputStream.write(initialText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            cipherOutputStream.close();

            byte [] vals = outputStream.toByteArray();
            encryptedText = Base64.encodeToString(vals, Base64.DEFAULT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        }
        return encryptedText;
    }
```

Here is the erot i get. I would like to success to keep my data in a secure place

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Unsupported key algorithm: EC. Only RSA supported
at com.cryptor.Cryptor.encryptString(Cryptor.java:108)
```

Comment: can you post your encryptString() method, please ?

Comment: @Bruno, Sorry i forgot this part, i just add it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where/when you generate your RSA key. On my side, I have done the following steps :

1. Create/retrieve the `Keystore`
2. Generate RSA keys with a `KeyPairGenerator` (be careful : different methods since Android M)

`val generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, CryptoConstants.ANDROID_KEY_STORE)`

Here, **ALGORITHM="RSA"** and not "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" and CryptoConstants.ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore" (for example)

3. Save keys in the `Keystore`
4. Encrypt with the public key
5. Decrypt with the private key

With these steps, my encryption methods are

```
fun encrypt(publicKey: PublicKey, rawText: ByteArray): String {
    try {
        val cipher = CipherUtil.getStandardCipherInstance(TRANSFORMATION) // TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
        val bytes = cipher.doFinal(rawText)
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, BASE64_SETTINGS) // BASE64_SETTINGS = Base64.NO_WRAP
    } catch (e: GeneralSecurityException) {
        throw SecurityException(e)
    }
}

fun decrypt(privateKey: PrivateKey, base64CipherBytes: ByteArray): ByteArray {
    try {
        val cipher = CipherUtil.getStandardCipherInstance(TRANSFORMATION) // TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)
        val encryptedData = Base64.decode(base64CipherBytes, BASE64_SETTINGS) // BASE64_SETTINGS
        return cipher.doFinal(encryptedData)
    } catch (e: GeneralSecurityException) {
        throw SecurityException(e)
    }
}
```

Btw, you can bypass the Base64 encoding if you don't need it.

Comment: I change "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" by "RSA" it solve the problem here and encrypt well, but now when i decrypt, i got "java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA" on `cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey)`. I also change RSAPrivateKey to PrivateKey else i got another error

Comment: CryptoConstants is not recognize from my Android studio, is it normal?

Comment: Yes, it's mine, sorry. Just use any string you want to identify your key store instead of CryptoConstants.ANDROID_KEY_STORE. I update my answer

Comment: Do i need a second var? i only put 'KeyPairGenerator.getInstance'ALGORITHM)". And i still don't get over the error 'java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA', what make the error and how can i solve it? i find nothing on web about it.

Comment: The 2nd parameter is is provider: We are saying that the algorithm we want to use this keygenerator for will be RSA, and we want to save the keys/data in the AndroidKeyStore. Here is a very good article : https://medium.com/@josiassena/using-the-android-keystore-system-to-store-sensitive-information-3a56175a454b

Comment: I used [link](https://medium.com/@josiassena/using-the-android-keystore-system-to-store-sensitive-information-3a56175a454b) and [link](https://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-keystore-store-passwords-sensitive-information-623779/). But don't matter what im doing i still get the same error, 'java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA' on 'Cipher output = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            output.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);'

Comment: To generate my keys, I use "RSA". But, when I use Cipher, I specify "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"